# blueimp not able to submit files to server

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I am using *blueimp* plugin to upload multiple files(Drag and Drop).

**HTML Snippet**

```
    <div id="myFileUpload" class="container uploadContainer">
        <div class="clr">
            <div class="clr">
                <h4 id="count" class="float-left"></h4>
                <button for="uploadedFile" id="triggerUploadedFile"
                    class="float-right">Add Files</button>
            </div>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="uploadedFile"
                style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div id="dndBorder" class='dndBorder clr'>
            <span><h4>
                    <font color="#D3D3D3">Drag and drop the files or folders
                        here </font>
                </h4></span>

        </div>
        <!-- The global file processing state -->
        <span class="fileupload-process"></span>

        <!-- File Grid View  -->
        <div class="clr tab-presentation-div">
            <div class="">
                <table role="presentation" class="clear-margin">
                    <tbody class="files"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr">
            <button id="startUpload" class="float-right field-button-action">Start Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Following are script required to initialize plugin.

```
$j("#myFileUpload").fileupload({
    dropZone: $j('#myFileUpload'),
    url: lUrl,
    autoUpload: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data){
        // Iterating and adding files to presentation area so that user can see file he added
    }
    submit: function(e, data){
        // Needs to add some additional Form data.
    }
});
$j("#startUpload").click(function(e){
    $j("#myFileUpload").data().submit();
});
```

when i am clicking on **start upload** button i am getting submit not a function error.

when i inspected $j("#myFileUpload").data() then observed that $j("#myFileUpload").data() does not have any submit event attached to it.

can any body please tell what is missing.

Thanks in advance.